# how to access 6 different functions within for loop in C?

Tags: c, function, for-loop, function-call

I am writing a code in C. I have to calculate some coefficients named as:

```
k1, k2, k3, k4
```

I have 6 different functions named as:

```
func1, func2, func3, .....func6
```

Very inefficient way is to write a code like this:

```
/* find k1 for all 6 functions */

/* k[0][0] is k1 for func1 */
/* k[0][1] is k1 for func2 */
   ......
   ......
/* k[0][5] is k1 for func6 */

/* h is some constant */

            k[0][0] = h*func1()
            k[0][1] = h*func2()
            k[0][2] = h*func3()
            k[0][3] = h*func4()
            k[0][4] = h*func5()
            k[0][5] = h*func6()
```

Similarly I have to find out k2 for all 6 functions.

Again very inefficient way would be :

```
        k[1][0] = h*func1()
        k[1][1] = h*func2()
        k[1][2] = h*func3()
        k[1][3] = h*func4()
        k[1][4] = h*func5()
        k[1][5] = h*func6()
```

And similar things for remaining k3 & k4 would be:

```
 /* find K3 for all 6 functions */
   .............
   .............
 /* find K4 for all 6 functions */
   .............
   .............
```

I want to avoid all this.

I want a way so that I can call 6 functions for each coefficient k within a `for` loop. Something like this:

```
for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
  {
     for(j=0; j<=5; j++)
       {
          k[i][j] =  h*func[...]
          /* where func[...] means some way for calling 6 functions */
       }
  }
```

May be some array of functions ??

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually the code you say is inefficent is the fastest one.

Comment: @Fredrik-- efficiency is not always about speed of execution.

Comment: @Fredrik: How it is the fastest one ?

Comment: @atom because looking up function pointers in an array will be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare an array of pointers to functions of the same type. Some people prefer to use `typedef`s for this, but you can also declare the array directly. If `f` is a pointer to a function, you can call the function with `(*f)(...)`, where the ellipsis represents the arguments. But you can also call the function with `f(...)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double f1(int);
double f2(int);
double f3(int);
double f4(int);
double f5(int);
double f6(int);

int main(void)
{
    /* With typedef */
//    typedef double (*Fn_ptr)(int);
//    Fn_ptr funcs[6] = { f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6 };

    /* Without typedef */
    double (*funcs[6])(int) = { f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6 };

    double k[4][6];
    double h = 0.1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            k[i][j] =  h*funcs[j](i);
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            printf("%10f", k[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}

double f1(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}

double f2(int x)
{

    return x + 2;
}

double f3(int x)
{
    return x + 3;
}

double f4(int x)
{
    return x + 4;
}

double f5(int x)
{
    return x + 5;
}

double f6(int x)
{
    return x + 6;
}
```

Comment: What is meaning of  'funcs[j](i)'  e.g. funcs[5](3) ? Does this point to 5th function or 3rd function ? And where do I put my arguments to functions ?

Comment: `funcs[]` is an array of function pointers; `funcs[5]` is the sixth function pointer in the array, that is, `f6` in the above code. Remember that arrays are zero-indexed in C. `funcs[5](3)` is equivalent to the function call: `f6(3)`.

Comment: Is number 3 in above comment an argument to function f6 ?

Comment: What is size_t ? Is it necessary ?

Comment: `size_t` is an `unsigned` integer type that is guaranteed by the Standard to be capable of holding any array index. It is the correct type to use for array indices, and it should probably be used whenever possible. Note, for example, that the `sizeof` operator returns type `size_t`.

Comment: I don't see any difference between "with typedef" & "without typedef". Also way of calling functions is also same. Am I correct ?

Comment: Calling functions is the same in both instances. With and without `typedef` has to do with declarations. `typedef double (*Fn_ptr)(int)` establishes that `Fn_ptr` should be an alias for the type "pointer to a function taking an `int` argument and returning type `double`". Then `Fn_ptr funcs[6]` declares and array of 6 objects of this type. Some find this style more readable. An alternative is to omit the `typedef`, writing the declaration directly: `double (*funcs[6])(int)`. This says that `funcs` is an array of 6 pointers to functions, each taking an `int` argument and returning type `double`

Comment: In function call  **funcs[2])(3)** here number 2 is function number 3. While in the declaration **double (*funcs[6])(int) = { f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6 };**,  number 6 is total number of functions. So square bracket [ ] serves two purposes at the same time ?

Comment: Yes. This is basic C syntax. In array declarations a number in square brackets specifies the size of the array. In other expressions the square brackets indicate array subscripting. Arrays are zero-indexed in C, so the first element of `funcs` is `funcs[0]`, and the last element is `funcs[5]`.

Answer (score 1):

*If* all the 6 functions have the same prototype, I assume they have - for example receives `void` and returns `int`, then you can use an array of function pointers:

```
typedef int (*FUNCTION_PTR)(void);

FUNCTION_PTR funcs[6] = { func1, func2, ... };

for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        k[i][j] = h * func[j]();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put arguments to functions ? My 6 functions have same prototype; but they have different definitions.